# Application error when deploying on heroku

Tags: heroku, react-boilerplate

I used react-boilerplate, to create app. It works fine on localhost. I push it on heroku to deploy it. Seems it deployed without any problem. But at the end I get an Application error.I tried delete node_modules, and npm install again, but it not work. Below is a log from heroku when I deploy through connect to github.

```
      Node.js app detected
   Creating runtime environment

   NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
   NODE_VERBOSE=false
   NODE_ENV=production
   NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
   Installing binaries
   engines.node (package.json):  >=5
   engines.npm (package.json):   >=3

   Resolving node version >=5...
   Downloading and installing node 10.1.0...
   Bootstrapping npm >=3 (replacing 5.6.0)...
   npm 6.0.1 installed
   Restoring cache
   Loading 2 from cacheDirectories (default):
   - node_modules
   - bower_components (not cached - skipping)
   Building dependencies
   Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)

   > react-boilerplate@3.5.0 preinstall /tmp/build_230c7b1d6b919fe2d3adb3c6e7724ba0
   > npm run npmcheckversion


   > react-boilerplate@3.5.0 npmcheckversion /tmp/build_230c7b1d6b919fe2d3adb3c6e7724ba0
   > node ./internals/scripts/npmcheckversion.js


   > react-boilerplate@3.5.0 postinstall /tmp/build_230c7b1d6b919fe2d3adb3c6e7724ba0
   > npm run build:dll


   > react-boilerplate@3.5.0 build:dll /tmp/build_230c7b1d6b919fe2d3adb3c6e7724ba0
   > node ./internals/scripts/dependencies.js

   up to date in 17.48s
   [!] 467 vulnerabilities found [26996 packages audited]
   Severity: 418 Low | 46 Moderate | 3 High
   Run `npm audit` for more detail

   Running heroku-postbuild

   > react-boilerplate@3.5.0 heroku-postbuild /tmp/build_230c7b1d6b919fe2d3adb3c6e7724ba0
   > npm run build


   > react-boilerplate@3.5.0 prebuild /tmp/build_230c7b1d6b919fe2d3adb3c6e7724ba0
   > npm run build:clean


   > react-boilerplate@3.5.0 build:clean /tmp/build_230c7b1d6b919fe2d3adb3c6e7724ba0
   > rimraf ./build


   > react-boilerplate@3.5.0 build /tmp/build_230c7b1d6b919fe2d3adb3c6e7724ba0
   > cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config internals/webpack/webpack.prod.babel.js --color -p --progress --hide-modules --display-optimization-bailout

   Hash: 0eb898bf6ee4193afaf8
   Version: webpack 3.5.5
   Time: 12067ms
   Asset       Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
   main.6fc0e199fe5ea4638163.js     496 kB       0  [emitted]  main
   index.html  799 bytes          [emitted]
   sw.js    16.3 kB          [emitted]

   WARNING in OfflinePlugin: Cache pattern [*.chunk.js] did not match any assets
   Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
   1 asset
   Child __offline_serviceworker:
   1 asset
   Caching build
   Clearing previous node cache
   Saving 2 cacheDirectories (default):
   - node_modules
   - bower_components (nothing to cache)
   Pruning devDependencies

   > pre-commit@1.2.2 uninstall node_modules/pre-commit
   > node uninstall.js

   removed 1491 packages in 17.153s
   [!] 12 vulnerabilities found [601 packages audited]
   Severity: 7 Low | 2 Moderate | 3 High
   Run `npm audit` for more detail

   Build succeeded!
   Discovering process types
   Procfile declares types     -> (none)
   Default types for buildpack -> web
   Compressing...
   Done: 30.2M
   Launching...
   Released v9
   https://todotest1991.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

[Here links to github](https://github.com/Dollar1610/TodoApp)

Also I tried in command line using this command: `heroku logs --tail -app fast-lake`. And I get this:

```
D:\lessons\Test todo\1\vitalytodo>heroku logs --tail --app fast-lake-29656
Starting process with command `npm start`
react-boilerplate@3.5.0 start /app
cross-env NODE_ENV=development no
de server
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:573
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'glob'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:571:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/
modules/cjs/loader.js:497:25)
at Module.require (internal/modules
/cjs/loader.js:626:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/he
lpers.js:20:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/app/interna
ls/webpack/webpack.dev.babel.js:7:14)
at Module._compile (internal/module
s/cjs/loader.js:678:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (i
nternal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cj
s/loader.js:589:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/
cjs/loader.js:528:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/
modules/cjs/loader.js:520:3)
npm ERR! react-boilerplate@3.5.0 st
art: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node server`
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! Failed at the react-boiler
plate@3.5.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a pro
blem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run
can be found in:
npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2018-0
5-15T07_30_04_738Z-debug.log
Process exited with status 1
State changed from starting to crashed
State changed from crashed to starting
Starting process with command `npm start`

> react-boilerplate@3.5.0 start /app
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node server

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:573
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'glob'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:571:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:497:25)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:626:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/app/internals/webpack/webpack.dev.babel.js:7:14)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:678:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:589:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:528:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:520:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! react-boilerplate@3.5.0 start: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node 
server`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! Failed at the react-boilerplate@3.5.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely 
additional logging output above.
npm ERR!

npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2018-05-15T07_30_12_052Z-debug.log
npm ERR! A complete log of this run
can be found in:
State changed from starting to crashed
Process exited with status 1
heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/" host=fast-lake-29656.herokuapp.com 
request_id=6794d470
-6b00-4ed2-8f5e-892e6ade5891 fwd="145.255.9.159" dyno= connect= service= 
status=
503 bytes= protocol=https
heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=fast-lake-29656.herokuapp.com 
 request_
 id=15da6f9b-2abd-414d-88cb-849d4fd9eeec fwd="145.255.9.159" dyno= connect= 
service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: Why downvoted, how can i give logs froms CLI?

Comment: Hi! You should be able to copy and paste text from your terminal app. Depending on your terminal app, it might work a little bit different than in other applications. If you are using the standard Windows command prompt, you might want to have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11543578/copy-text-from-a-windows-cmd-window-to-clipboard

Comment: delete image, and add logs

Comment: Cool! I changed my vote...