# How do I copy/paste in Anaconda prompt?

Tags: windows, cmd, anaconda

I work on Windows 7. Have the following problem. Want to copy a text from Anaconda prompt to a website.

I marked a given line in Ancaconda prompt, I click 'mark' in the menu, mark the text - but when I click right the marking vanishes. I also tried <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd> but it doesn't work either. What is my mistake?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy text from a Windows CMD window to clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11543578/copy-text-from-a-windows-cmd-window-to-clipboard)

Comment: Note that this is not specific to the Anaconda Prompt, which is just using the Windows Command Prompt

Answer (score 15):

Step 1: Right click on the title bar of the Anaconda Prompt.

Step 2: Select Properties.

Step 3: Under Options section, select all the check boxes of Edit Options and Text Selection, then click OK

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

**Ctrl+C** to copy anything from anywhere, as usual
**RIGHT CLIC** inside Anaconda Prompt window to paste

Answer (score 1):

1. Right click on the title bar of the Anaconda Prompt.
2. Select Default Value instead of Properties.
3. Check last term of Edit Options.
4. Restart the Prompt.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple.

USE:

Copy: `Enter`
Paste: `Ctrl +V`

Comment: What do you mean by "enter"?

Comment: `Enter` or `Return` key on your keyboard

Answer (score 0):

I found how to do this.

You select the text you want, then *don't * do Ctrl-c or any other combination. Instead right click the title bar and check in the menu that appears a "Copy" option. (I think it is inside another menu).
Once you do this, the text is copied in the correct way and you can just Ctrl-V in your own application, editor , etc