# Django "Python manage.py runserver" command gives an error and then freezes the command line

Tags: python, django

I'm learning django and i'm trying to run "Python manage.py runserver" it gives me a error that is too long but i took a screenshot I"m using python 3.8.2.[image: stackoverflow error]

Comment: I'd suggest copying and pasting this into the body of your question. Otherwise, people with similar questions won't be able to find this answer as a picture is non-searchable.

Comment: I can't copy what's in the command line

Comment: It looks like your version of Django doesn’t support Python 3.8. Please upgrade to the latest Django 3.0.X or 2.2.X long term support release.

Comment: Hmm -- that doesn't seem right, let's see if we can figure out how. What kind of system are you using?

Comment: @Pythonfan, sure you can. Click the window icon, then Edit, then Mark. Select whatever you want to copy and right-click or press enter. Then paste. See [Copy text from a Windows CMD window to clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11543578/354577)

Comment: Thanks to everyone I fixed the problem yesterday sorry for not answering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you in correct directory? You can call "python manage.py runserver" only in directory where a file manage.py is placed. Have you created project and new app?