# How to capture the output of command window using VBS and notify user with a played sound?

Tags: automation, vbscript

I have successfully managed to use VBS to open `cmd` for writing data to a database and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> key twice.

Here is my code:

```
Set wshshell = wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
Wshshell.run "cmd" 
wscript.sleep 100
wshshell.sendkeys "firebase-import --service_account C:\Users --database_url https://firebaseio.com  --json C:\Users\Zed\testing.json"
wscript.sleep 100
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```

Here is the console output:

```
firebase-import --service_account C:\Users\Zed\private-firebase-adminsdk-private --path /Jobs/Test --database_url https://private.firebaseio.com  --json C:\Users\Zed\testing.json
All data at https://private.firebaseio.com/Jobs/Test will be overwritten.
Press <enter> to proceed, Ctrl-C to abort.

Reading C:\Users\Zed\testing.json... (may take a minute)
Preparing JSON for import... (may take a minute)
Importing [==================================================] 100% (1/1)

Import completed.
```

I have also managed to play a sound using VBS. Here is the code:

```
Dim oPlayer
Set oPlayer = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX")

' Play audio
oPlayer.URL = "C:\Users\Zed\notify.mp3"
oPlayer.controls.play 
While oPlayer.playState <> 1 ' 1 = Stopped
  WScript.Sleep 100
Wend

' Release the audio file
oPlayer.close
```

Now, how to combine these two, so the sound only plays when `Import completed` message is shown in the console window?

Comment: If you would have read the file [README.md](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firebase-import) for `firebase-import` carefully displayed also on homepage of this utility, you would have saved yourself a lot of time after reading in __Usage__ section about: `--force   Don't prompt before overwriting data.` It would be also good to read [Copy text from a Windows CMD window to clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11543578/) because of copying output text as text would have saved you again time and you would have made most like __all__ strings private which you do not want public.

Comment: Open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/), run `where firebase-import` and look on the full qualified file name. I haven't installed this utility. But if the output file name ends with `.exe`, the execution of `cmd.exe` would not be needed at all as the executable can be executed directly from within the Visual Basic script. You could use the [.run](https://ss64.com/vb/run.html) method to run `cmd.exe` or `firebase-import` (on being an executable) with `bWaitOnReturn` set to `TRUE`. The [.exec](https://ss64.com/vb/exec.html) method would give you the option to capture output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Mofi pointed out in the comments, you can disable the `All data at https://private.firebaseio.com/Jobs/Test will be overwritten.` prompt which gets you away from sending keystrokes. You can simply use the Windows Script Host `Run` method:

```
Dim objWshShell
Dim sCommand

sCommand = "firebase-import --service_account C:\Users --database_url https://firebaseio.com  --json C:\Users\Zed\testing.json"

Set objWshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objWshShell.Run sCommand, 1, True
```

You can also wrap your code that plays a sound into a `Sub`:

```
Sub PlaySound(p_sURL)

    Dim oPlayer
    Set oPlayer = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX")
    
    ' Play audio
    oPlayer.URL = p_sURL
    oPlayer.Controls.play
    While oPlayer.playState <> 1 ' 1 = Stopped
      WScript.Sleep 100
    Wend
    
    ' Release the audio file
    oPlayer.Close

End Sub
```

You can call this subroutine after `objWshShell.Run sCommand, 1, true`:

```
objWshShell.Run sCommand, 1, true
PlaySound ("C:\Users\Zed\notify.mp3")
```

**EDIT**

In order to determine the outcome of the import process, you can redirect the output to a text file:

```
sCommand = "cmd /c firebase-import --service_account C:\Users --database_url https://firebaseio.com  --json C:\Users\Zed\testing.json > C:\temp\output.txt"
```

You can then read the file and look for `"Import Completed"`:

```
Sub CheckOutput()
    Dim sOutput
    Dim objFSO, objFileReader

    Set objFSO  = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFileReader = objFSO.OpenTextFile("c:\temp\output.txt", 1)
    sOutput = objFileReader.ReadAll
    objFileReader.Close

    If InStr(sOutput, "Import Completed") > 0 Then
        PlaySound ("C:\Users\Zed\notify.mp3")
    Else
        PlaySound ("C:\Users\Zed\error.mp3")
    End If

End Sub
```

You can use this sub after running the command:

```
objWshShell.Run sCommand, 1, true
CheckOutput
```