# Add Print Directory Feature to Windows Explorer Does Not Work

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-10, regedit

A standard implementation of this technique is provided at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/printing/add-print-directory-feature

Unfortunately it does not work for me. The Printdir.bat file is:

```
@echo off 
dir %1 /-p /o:gn > "%temp%\Listing" 
start /w notepad /p "%temp%\Listing"
del "%temp%\Listing"
exit
```

My implementation fails at the cmd level with the error:

> The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect".
> (The program continues and results in no file created since nothing is passed to notepad).

If run in the Windows directory, it runs fine.
Adding quotes around `"%1"` did not help and neither did `"%~1"`

Comment: Remove `@echo off` and replace `exit` by `pause`, then check in the Command Prompt window what `%1` becomes expanded to…

Comment: Replaced should be also `start /w notepad` by `%SystemRoot%\notepad.exe`.

Comment: What I get is: \"C:\Users\Roger\Documents|Custom Office Templates\"

Comment: What I get is:  C:WINDOWS\system32>dir \"C:\Users\Roger\Documents\Custom Office Templates\" /-p /o:gn  1>"C:\Users\Roger\AppData\Local\Temp\Listing"   Then the error The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. That is the directory that I was attempting to print.

Comment: It appears that the \ after dir is the problem. That is, dir \"C:\Users\.... should be dir "C:\Users\....   However, I do not know where it is coming from and how to fix it.

Comment: Run in a command prompt window `%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe QUERY "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\shell\Print_Directory_Listing\command" /ve`, [copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11543578/) the output information of this registry query, [edit] your question and add the output and copied information to the question. Then we can tell you how to fix the execution of `Printdir.bat` which you have obviously registered wrong. BTW: It should be registered with full qualified file name, i.e. drive+path+name+extension and not with just file name with extension.

Comment: Thanks for that excellent idea. Unfortunately, I had already edited the registry to eliminate the extra \. I have run your suggestion and received the following, now correct response: HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\shell\Print_Directory_Listing\command
    (Default)    REG_SZ    Printdir.bat "%1\" Since I found the same incorrect instructions on four websites, it is apparent that three of the "authors" had never tried out their solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instructions (repeated at several sites) created a file PrintDirectoryListing.reg with steps 3 and 6 creating a command Printdir.bat \"%1\"
From the comments by aschipfl and Mofi, I was able to troubleshoot the activity and edit the registry, eliminate the \ before "%1" making both commands Printdir.bat "%1\".
Now everything works properly. Thanks again to aschipfl and Mofi