# Copy all text from Command Window programatically

Tags: cmd, windows-10, clipboarddata

[This article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11543578/copy-text-from-a-windows-cmd-window-to-clipboard) shows the well-known way to manually copy text from a Command window.

I'm looking for a way to do this programmatically. How could the cmd script that is running select all the text in its output window, and write it to a file?

I've found [tools](https://nircmd.nirsoft.net/savescreenshot.html) to do a screen capture into a file, but that may miss output if it has scrolled out of view? I'm looking for a way to capture an unattended cmd script's output (without modifying the whole script to redirect every line to a file).

Possibly this could be done with the windows API by finding the cmd window, sending <kbd>CTRL-A</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL-C</kbd> keycodes, and then write the clipboard text to a file. [A possible approach for clip2txt is presented in this post](http://www.columbia.edu/%7Eem36/clip2txt.html).

Is there any other approach that should be considered?