# Any command to use in PowerShell to copy few lines from Console?

Tags: powershell

in my powershell script a lot of items are getting printed in the console.
I want to copy them and validate a data is present or not. Any way I can do it?

I am yet to get any solution for this. thank you in advance

Comment: Why not just do a logic check for each line written, and decide to catch whatever you choose in real time?  Any controlled output can be written to the screen and to a file in real-time using the ```Tee-Object``` cmdlet or other logging methods. As others have mentioned, you can just use PS transcription, and review/parse that log after your code is complete.

Answer (score 2):

One Way to record everything thats going on with your Script is [Powershell Transcript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.host/start-transcript?view=powershell-7.3)

Or you can just Copy the Output from your Console to a Text file in Notepad++ or something like that...

But to be honest I don't quite understand what you are trying to achieve with that, wouldn't be the goal with a script that you don't have to check something like that?

My suggestion would be that you look for a way to validate anything you need within your Script, and maybe implement some sort of Logging to have the Option to review it when something has gone wrong...

Answer (score 2):

I used `$variable = command` and it is working.

Answer (score 1):

if your case is to validate your logs I suggest saving the logs into a file and then validating them and don't use the console for that purpose.
if you still want to copy them from the console try this: [Copy text from a Windows CMD window to clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11543578/copy-text-from-a-windows-cmd-window-to-clipboard)

Answer (score 1):

In your situation, i would use [Start-Transcript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.host/start-transcript?view=powershell-7.3) into a log file.

And then get information from the log file using filters.